# JSONDecoder - "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead."

Tags: ios, swift, decode, jsondecoder

So i am trying to decode a json and get this error.

This is the JSON :

```
{ "SERVERWebSystemInfoGet": { 
        "Return Code" : 0,
        "Return String" : "No Error",
        "Info" : "{\"IT\":\"IT109200310_0\",\"MAC\":\"00:40:7F:41:F8:81\",\"UUID\":\"uuid:858fba00-d3a0-11dd-a001-00407f41f881\",\"SN\":\"ENG031\",\"ModelNumber\":\"DH-390 2MP\",\"ModelName\":\"DH-390 2MP\",\"FwVer\":\"v1.0.0.34\",\"HwVer\":\"\",\"FriendlyName\":\"DH-390 2MP ENG031\",\"UpTime\":548}" }
}
```

This are my models :

```
struct Information: Codable {

    let ModelName : String?

}

struct GetInformation: Codable {

    let Info: [String: Information]?

}

struct WebSystemInfo: Codable {

    let SERVERWebSystemInfoGet: GetInformation?

}
```

This is the method :

```
func parseGetInfo(data: Data) {

    do {
        let info = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebSystemInfo.self, from: data)
        print(info)
    } catch let error{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And this is the error that i get :

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "SERVERWebSystemInfoGet", intValue: nil), 
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: "Info", intValue: nil)], 
>   debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Please learn to understand the decoding error messages, they are very descriptive.

The error says you are going to decode an dictionary but the actual object is a string (Info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
 "Info" : "{\"IT\":\"IT109200310_0\",\"MAC\":\"00:40:7F:41:F8:81\",\"UUID\":\"uuid:858fba00-d3a0-11dd-a001-00407f41f881\",\"SN\":\"ENG031\",\"ModelNumber\":\"DH-390 2MP\",\"ModelName\":\"DH-390 2MP\",\"FwVer\":\"v1.0.0.34\",\"HwVer\":\"\",\"FriendlyName\":\"DH-390 2MP ENG031\",\"UpTime\":548}" }
```

is a json string not a dictionary you need

```
let Info:String?
```

Comment: any idea  how to get a value from the result?
for example i want the  UUID value

Comment: either change server response to dictionary or look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621120/simple-and-clean-way-to-convert-json-string-to-object-in-swift ,,,,,,,,, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380140/5820010

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the `Info` value is actually a string and not a dictionary.
Notice that it starts with quotes.

Change the model to return Dictionary instead of String.

Answer (score 1):

You copied JSON which has escaped bits: `”` with `\”`, which makes the info-dictionary a string.

Try the following string with the escaping removed whether you can decode it.

```
{
  "SERVERWebSystemInfoGet": {
    "Return Code": 0,
    "Return String": "No Error",
    "Info": {
        "IT": "IT109200310_0",
        "MAC": "00:40:7F:41:F8:81",
        "UUID": "uuid:858fba00-d3a0-11dd-a001-00407f41f881",
        "SN":"ENG031",
        "ModelNumber": "DH-390 2MP",
        "ModelName": "DH-390 2MP",
        "FwVer": "v1.0.0.34",
        "HwVer": "x",
        "FriendlyName": "DH-390 2MP ENG031",
        "UpTime": "548"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can think about changing the server output if you can, or decoding `info` manually if you can’t by following [this guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/382-encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4), it starts at *Manual Encoding and Decoding* with the important bits.