# How to deserialize JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift

I want to decode a JSON file into model objects. Unfortunately it doesn't work in the right way. So I don't get errors, but the "decoding-result" don't corresponds to my expectations.
I have the following JSON file and I want to decode it in the shown structs. I have trimmed the json file. Why get I just one "slider image" instead of 5 (the property image of ImagesSlider contains an array with just the first image/element).
What am I missing?

**JSON:**

```
[{"imageSlider" : [{
        "image" : [{
             "imageId" : "1",
             "imageName" : "germany1",
             "imageBigName" : "germany1_BIG",
             "imageRights" : "Peter"
        }],
        "image" : [{
             "imageId" : "2",
             "imageName" : "germany2",
             "imageBigName" : "germany2_BIG",
             "imageRights" : "Peter"
        }],
        "image" : [{
             "imageId" : "3",
             "imageName" : "germany3",
             "imageBigName" : "germany3_BIG",
             "imageRights" : "Peter"
        }],
        "image" : [{
             "imageId" : "4",
             "imageName" : "germany4",
             "imageBigName" : "germany4_BIG",
             "imageRights" : "Peter"
        }],
        "image" : [{
             "imageId" : "5",
             "imageName" : "germany5",
             "imageBigName" : "germany5_BIG",
             "imageRights" : "Peter"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

**Swift:**

```swift
struct CountryModel : Decodable, Equatable {    
    var countryName : String
    var inhabitants : String
    var capital : String
    var currency : String
    var imageName : String
    var imageSlider: [ImagesSlider]
}

struct ImagesSlider : Decodable, Equatable {
    var image: [Image]
}

struct Image : Decodable, Equatable {
    var imageId: String
    var imageName: String
    var imageBigName: String
    var imageRights: String
}
```

**Decoding:**

```swift
func loadData() -> [CountryModel] {
    var data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json") else {
        fatalError("Error")
    }

    data = try! Data(contentsOf: file)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try! decoder.decode([CountryModel].self, from: data)

}
```

Thanks for your help...

Edit:
My question isn't solved by the linked question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple and clean way to convert JSON string to Object in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621120/simple-and-clean-way-to-convert-json-string-to-object-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json looks wrong, remember that you should have only one unique key per json object. Right now is:

```
[
  {
    "imageSlider": [
      {
        "image": [
          {
            "imageId": "1",
            "imageName": "germany1",
            "imageBigName": "germany1_BIG",
            "imageRights": "Peter"
          }
        ],
        "image": [
          {
            "imageId": "2",
            "imageName": "germany2",
            "imageBigName": "germany2_BIG",
            "imageRights": "Peter"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And it should be like this:

```
[
    {
      "imageSlider": [
        {
          "image": [
            {
              "imageId": "1",
              "imageName": "germany1",
              "imageBigName": "germany1_BIG",
              "imageRights": "Peter"
            },
            {
              "imageId": "2",
              "imageName": "germany2",
              "imageBigName": "germany2_BIG",
              "imageRights": "Peter"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Notice  that "germany2" item is inside of the array of image.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
  let country = try decoder.decode([CountryModel].self, from: jsonData)
  print(country[0].imageSlider[0].image.count)
} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}

// Console message
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your JSON contains multiple `Images` object **with the same key**! That is not valid and each one overwrites others (randomly probably). You should turn that json to array of objects:

```
[{
    "imageSlider" : [{
        "image" : [{
            "imageId" : "1",
            "imageName" : "germany1",
            "imageBigName" : "germany1_BIG",
            "imageRights" : "Peter"
        }]},{
            "image" : [{
            "imageId" : "2",
            "imageName" : "germany2",
            "imageBigName" : "germany2_BIG",
            "imageRights" : "Peter"
        }]}
    }]
}]
```

Also other keys of the `CountryModel` should be presented since all of them are non-optional.