# Convert array string to array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I have string:

```
content (String) : "[{id: \"10884\", name: \"Henry\"}, {id: \"85474\", name: \"Jack\"}]"
```

How can I convert this string to array

Desired results:

```
[{id: "10884", name: "Henry"}, {id: "85474", name: "Jack"}]
```

I'm trying:

```
let data = content.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

let stringsArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject]

print(stringsArray)
```

But stringsArray print is nil

I'm using swift version 5

I'm newbie IOS. Many thanks

Comment: [Simple and clean way to convert JSON string to Object in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621120/simple-and-clean-way-to-convert-json-string-to-object-in-swift)

Comment: @NiravD I'm try but results alway return nil

Comment: What you tried update your question with what your tried

Comment: You are casting result into the dictionary it is an array of dictionary also don't force wrap your `data`, this will crash your app if the data is nil, instead of that use `if let` or `guard let` to optionally wrapped data

Comment: I'm trying ***as? [[String : Any?]]*** the result is still nil

Comment: Its because your key id and name also need to be wrapped in a double quote in JSON string also you don't need to add `?` after `Any` it is simply  `[[String : Any]]`

Comment: I'm sorry but results is still nill

Comment: It work when wrapped in a double quote of key. But is there any way to make it work even without wrapping quotes in key. I also removed ? after Any

Comment: @khjfquantumjj Hi, I think issue of me is Array of Dictionary not JSON object

Comment: No, you need to add a double quote around the key, valid JSON always have double quote around key

Comment: You need to learn the terminology right: your desired result is not array, it's dictionary; your original is not a string, it's an array of JSON objcts (with quotes escaped, but unclear if this escaping is artifact of showin the value or it's actually escaped...

Comment: And there's a gazillion of answers on how to convert an array of json objects to dictionary for swift.

Comment: maybe my problem is solved